# I want to print number of 1 and number 0 from given string how can I?

Tags: java

String str="1011101110";

see here str is complete one string but i want seperate each digit and and want to print total number of 0 and 1

Comment: OK. And what stops you from achieving this goal?  Are you familiar with `charAt()` function?

Comment: Yes I know charAt() function

Comment: Then what is stopping you from using it to access each character in string?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help **must** include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

See if that works for you

```
num_of_0 = 0;
num_of_1 = 0;
String s = "1011101110";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
   char c = s.charAt(i);
   if (c.equals("0"))
     num_of_0 = num_of_0  + 1
   else
     num_of_1 = num_of_1  + 1
}
System.out.println(num_of_0);
System.out.println(num_of_1);
```

Comment: If you already have `char` why do you compare it with a `String`?

Answer (score 0):

First split string into string array then sum these values.

You can use below approach:

```
String s = "1011101110";
String[] ls = s.split("");
int totalNumberOfZero = 0;
int totalNumberOfOne = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < ls.length; i++){ 
    if(ls[i].equals("0"))
       totalNumberOfZero++;
    else
       totalNumberOfOne++;
}

System.out.println(totalNumberOfZero);
System.out.println(totalNumberOfOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach but still divides the array into characters.  It does assume that the string only contains 1's and 0's.

```
  String s = "1011101110";
  int[] count = new int[2];
  for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
     count[c - '0']++;
  }
  System.out.println("0's count = " + count[0]);
  System.out.println("1's count = " + count[1]);
```